# Replace everything from a string when it reaches a match

Tags: python

Given:

```
path = 'abc/dfg/zxc'
```

Is there a way to replace the string before the first '/' with '.' ?

Expected result:

```
'./dfg/zxc'
```

What i have tried, this approah is messy and i am wondering if there is a cleaner one to solving this issue?:

```
 lst = path.split()

from_index = lst[0].index('/')
to_index = len(lst[0])

new_list = lst[0][from_index -1 + 1:to_index]
new_str = ''.join(new_list)
new_str2 = '.' + new_str
```

Comment: What have you tried, and what exactly is the problem with it?

Comment: ```"." + path[path.find("/"):]``` should do the trick if you want a quick hack

Comment: @jonrsharpe I updated the post with I have tried, the issue is its a lot of work for maybe a cleaner aproach

Comment: For the rest of the down votes, care to explain why so i can improve the post ?

Comment: Your approach doesn't make any sense: `path.split()` is just `['abc/dfg/zxc']`; `lst.index('/')` is a `ValueError`; and `lst[from_index, 1:to_index]` is a `TypeError`.

Comment: Corrected the bad code.

Comment: I'm trying correct my wrongs with this post, I improved the post as you requested, is there anything else I can do to improve it and maybe get some feedback if what i changed is good or not? Down Votes removed if you see fit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using a regex match/substitution?

```
import re

path = 'abc/dfg/zxc'

print(re.sub(r'^\w+/', './', path))
'./dfg/zxc'
```

Answer (score 0):

You should do like this:

```
path = path.replace(path[0:path.find("/")], ".")
```

Comment: This will not work if the substring from the start until the first slash is also found elsewhere in the string. So if `path = 'abc/xyz/abc'`, your code will result in `path == './xyz/.'`

Comment: It seems to work for me `>>> path = 'asd/ewqe/dsad'
>>> path = path.replace(path[0:path.find("/")], ".")
>>>
>>> path
'./ewqe/dsad'`

Comment: Out of sheer curiosity, how can I modify this to replace everything with a '.' that is in front of the last '/' is it possible or just with regex?

Comment: @Henry-G 'asd' is not included in 'dsad'. The problem mentionned in the first comment is real.

Comment: Oh yeah, now I understand, thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is a way to use the [`split`](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjX07jc79bpAhVhg-AKHSdmABsQFjAAegQIBhAB&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3schools.com%2Fpython%2Fref_string_split.asp&usg=AOvVaw3ObNZd2dEZ0iYJs1PNiEfZ) method:

```
path = f"./{path.split('/',1)[1]}"

print(path)
```

Output:

```
'./dfg/zxc'
```